# TFS/MTM export test cases by suite - shared steps and parameters

Tags: c#, tfs

So I am creating a tool for my organization somewhat similar to TestCaseExtractor on CodePlex. In addition to working with the newer version of the ALM, I want to export shared steps and iterations that correspond with parameters. (I am NOT trying to export results, JUST the plan data.) I wish Microsoft did a better job with API documentation. They used to do object model diagrams that were awesome. So IF you know of an object model diagram of this stuff, then you are even more my hero. So here is my method:

```
private void WriteCases(ITestSuiteBase suite, Exporter exporter)
    {
        foreach (var testCase in suite.TestCases)
        {
            exporter.WriteTestCaseTitle(testCase.Id.ToString(), testCase.TestCase.Title);
            exporter.WriteTestCaseDescription(testCase.TestCase.Description);
            exporter.objWriter.WriteLine("<table border='1' width='100%>'");
            exporter.objWriter.WriteLine("<tr><th width='50%'>Step</th><th widht='50%'>Expected Result</th></tr>");
            foreach (var action in testCase.TestCase.Actions)
            {
                string strStep = "";
                string strExpectedResult = "";
                if (action is ITestStep)
                {
                    ITestStep step = action as ITestStep;
                    strStep = step.Title;
                    strExpectedResult = step.ExpectedResult;
                }

                // TODO: Come back to this. Need shared steps fer sure.
                //else if (action is ISharedStepReference)
                //{
                //    ISharedStepReference sharedStep = action as ISharedStepReference;
                //    ISharedStep oldShareStep = sharedStep.FindSharedStep();
                //    foreach (var testAction in oldShareStep.Actions)
                //    {

                //    }
                //}
                exporter.objWriter.WriteLine("<tr><td>" + strStep + "</td><td>" + strExpectedResult + "</td></tr>");
            }
```

You can see the commented code where I think I have a start on the shared steps. But I cannot see any properties or anything for getting to the steps and actual results. So I am missing something.

I have no idea how to get the iterations for parameters in the test case. Any help is appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I wound up figuring it out.

https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/5356287d-2bf4-42c4-b28b-a19c5fcf94f8/tfs-mtm-extensibility-object-model-cannot-find-object-model-reference?forum=vsmantest

This is for anyone else who might wish to do this in the future.